# How to modify C# Chart control chartArea percentages

Tags: c#, mschart

If I have a chart control with 2 `chartAreas` in it, the chart control by default puts the chartAreas on top of each other makes each area take 50% of the available size of the chart control.

Is there a way to change the chartAreas' percent so that I could say, have the top chart take 75% of the area, and the bottom chart take 25%?

Comment: @Peretz For this part I'm using the designer to generate the chart.  While I could copy that code, I'm not sure it would be all that helpful.  It is just a standard chart with 2 chartAreas in it.  There is no code of my own that affects this, just the designer.  I am trying to see if somebody does know the code to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, I eventually found it, but I do not think that it is very well documented.  There each `chartArea` has the property [ChartArea.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.position.aspx).  This property of the type [ElementPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.elementposition.aspx), and contains 4 properties that are relevant to this problem.

Height:  Gets or sets the height of a chart element.
Width:   Gets or sets the width of a chart element.
X:  Gets or sets the relative X-coordinate of the top-left corner of an applicable chart element.
Y:  Gets or sets the relative Y-coordinate of the top-left corner of an applicable chart element.

When you dig deeper, the `Height` and `Width` properties are also stated in relative coordinates, such that you can only input 0 - 100.

Basically, you have to change each height, and each Y to move shift them.  After the initial creation, it will not automatically adjust the other numbers.

For instance, if I just change the `Height` of chartArea[1] to something smaller, it will still be anchored where it was previously, as would make sense, leaving a lot of white space below it.

If I then increase the `Height` of chartArea[0], it may draw over chartArea[1] that we just resized.  So then I have to set the `Y` of chartArea[1] to move it down, so that it is not drawn over, and the white space is gone.

So, to get something similar to what I asked in the question, I set it to:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 60;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Y = 70;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Height = 20;
```

To make this explanation a bit more clear, I will refer to the Chart control that these chartAreas are in as "the parent".

These are percentages, but for this example, let us assume that the parent's size is 100 pixels.

This sets the first chartArea start displaying at 10 px, and makes it about 60px tall.  It then starts displaying the second chartArea at 70px, and makes it about 20px tall.
If this chart was 200px tall, then the proportions would be the same, but the actually pixels would be double (so setting the first chart area to 60 would make it 120px tall).

I did pad this a bit more in my real program, because this has titles overwriting axis labels, but I felt these numbers helped explain it better.

Comment: This trashes the chart if done while it is not visible to the user (I have my chart on a separate TabPage and it only works ok if called *after* the chart is presented to the user eyes).

Comment: The only adequate place (producing the correct result) to put it I could find so far is the chart_Paint event handler (but not PrePaint/PostPaint or anywhere else). But it produces some visible trash when de-maximizing the window.

Comment: The best result I could get was by putting it to the Paint event handler of another control on the same TabPage but it is still not perfect and also seems dirty hack.

Answer (score 3):

You could also set the second chart .Y position to the bottom of the first chart.  That way you only need to worry about where the first chart is located.  The code looks something like this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Y = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Height = 60;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Y = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position.Bottom;
chart1.ChartAreas[1].Position.Height = 20;
```

You can also pad the .Y position, of course, depending on how much white space you want between the charts.  I used this approach for an application I built that uses multiple charts and it guarantees each chart will be properly located regardless of what is done with an individual chart.